# Iterating through 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need to create a method that will take a specific index in a 2D array and print out the values of the neighboring cells in clockwise order. I am not sure if I have to hardcode this program with a bunch of "If" statements or is there a looping way to achieve it?

The method takes in two parameters (rows and columns) and returns a String giving the values with a comma in between.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean or what you're asking.

Comment: are the rows and columns guaranteed to be more than one space from the edge? and do you want 4 neighbors, or 8? (i.e. including diagonals or not) Also, you say you want to return a string, but what about directly printing inside the method?

Comment: This can be done without hard coding. What did you try? Show us what you tried and we will help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this (constructor etc. omitted):

```
public class weird_array_class_of_doom{

    public array[][] the_thing;

    public void print_the_cells(int row, int col){
        System.out.print(array[row][col+1];
        System.out.print(array[row+1][col];
        System.out.print(array[row][col-1];
        System.out.print(array[row-1][col];
    }
}
```